# How to get column names of dataframe value x inside a function(x) in a mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to know how to get column names of an x while inside the function.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

data("penguins")
data("starwars")

penguins_ref <- penguins %>% 
  filter(species != "Chinstrap") %>% 
  select(1, 3:6) %>% 
  mutate(species = case_when(species == "Adelie" ~ "height",
                             species == "Gentoo" ~ "mass")) %>% 
  nest(data= -species) 

starwars_ref <- starwars %>% 
  select(c("name","height","mass")) %>% 
  mutate_at(c("height", "mass"),
            function(x) 
              (ifelse(x > 90,
                      penguins_ref[penguins_ref$species == colnames(x), "data"],
                      0
                      )))
```

In the code above, I failed to get column name from a dataframe value `penguins_ref[penguins_ref$species == colnames(x), "data"],` I want to have nested value inside the `starwars_ref` that is called from `penguins_ref`.

Thank you.

Comment: Inside your anonymous function, `x` isn't a column, it's a vector. You aren't going to be able to get its name directly like that, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Is there a workaround for this? In the end, I want to replace current value of `starwars_ref` that is more than 90 with nested data from `penguins_ref`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite sure what you expect as final output, but perhaps this is what you're after?

```r
starwars %>%
    select(name, height, mass) %>%
    pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "species") %>%
    left_join(penguins_ref, by = "species") %>%
    mutate(value = if_else(value > 90, data, list(value))) %>%
    select(-data) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = "species", values_from = "value")
## A tibble: 87 x 3
#      name               height             mass              
#      <chr>              <list>             <list>            
#    1 Luke Skywalker     <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    2 C-3PO              <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    3 R2-D2              <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    4 Darth Vader        <tibble [152 x 4]> <tibble [124 x 4]>
#    5 Leia Organa        <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    6 Owen Lars          <tibble [152 x 4]> <tibble [124 x 4]>
#    7 Beru Whitesun lars <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    8 R5-D4              <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    9 Biggs Darklighter  <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    10 Obi-Wan Kenobi     <tibble [152 x 4]> <dbl [174]>       
#    # ... with 77 more rows
```

The idea is to reshape `starwars` from wide to long, then join data from `penguins_ref` and replace values with data if `value > 90`; then reshape again to restore the original wide format.

Mind you, this seems like an awkward format: `height` and `weight` are `list` columns, with some entries being `tibble`s and others being scalars.